# Is there a formula for every discrete lookup table?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Formally, given integers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ and $p$, does there always exist $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\lfloor \alpha k+\beta\rfloor \equiv a_k\ (mod\ p)$ for $k=1,2,...,n$ ?

Comment: Without some conditions, of course not.  Let $p=2$.  If at least one of the even numbered $a_k$ is odd and one is even you are sunk.

Comment: @RossMillikan: that's not true as stated. With $p=2$, consider $n=4$ and $\alpha=0.3$ and $\beta=0.2$ and $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) \equiv (0,0,1,1)\pmod 2$.

Comment: @GregMartin:  I missed that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ could be noninteger

Comment: Some mucking about computationally seems to indicate that the answer is "no" for $p=3$, $n=4$, and $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) = (1,1,2,1)$.

Comment: @Greg Martin: I've verified the validity of your proposed counterexample.